# Sentry reported an error: Invalid token (http status: 401) - Sentry NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sentry

After integration sentry in my project the dev environment works fine but when I try to build the project with `yarn build` i face this error.

> Sentry CLI Plugin: Command failed: /Users/ishman/Desktop/sh/web-speedhome/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli releases new RUwbSqUhmn7T-kxjDJebz
> error: API request failed
> caused by: sentry reported an error: Invalid token (http status: 401)

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.

My configuration file for sentry

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs'
import { SENTRY_DSN } from './env'

Sentry.init({
  dsn: SENTRY_DSN,

  tracesSampleRate: 1,
  integrations: [new Sentry.BrowserTracing({})],

})
```

And my sentry.properties file

```
defaults.url=https://sentry.io/
defaults.org=org
defaults.project=project
auth.token=token
```

cli.executable=../../../.npm/_npx/a8388072043b4cbc/node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli

Comment: Have you figured it out? Running into the same issue for react native.

Comment: yes, somehow I didn't provide the correct token and DSN.. Providing the correct one solve my issue

Comment: Where can I get my token?

Comment: https://sentry.io/settings/account/api/auth-tokens/ use this url

Comment: https://sentry.xxx.com/settings/account/api/auth-tokens/